# Prompt user to input information, then sort the data

Tags: javascript, user-input, command-prompt, sorting

For a class project, I need to create a program in Javascript that asks a user to input 3 names, then sorts the names alphabetically and prints them on the screen.

I have figured out how to create a prompt box for the user to input the data, and I can get the program to then print the string that the user inputs onto the screen. However, I cannot figure out how to get Javascript to sort the string. I know that I need to use an array, but I'm not sure where to put the array, or how to get it to know user-inputted variables.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<html>
<script> 

function disp_prompt() 
      {
      var names=prompt("Please enter three names","Names")
      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML= names
      }

</script> 


<center><input type="button" onclick="disp_prompt()" value="Click Here"></center>
<br>

<h2><center><div id="msg"></div></center></h2>
</html>
```

Comment: Theres only one prompt how the user enter 3 names?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any idea of what to do with the string? Hints: [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) functions

Answer (score 4):

The whole thing could look like

```
var namesToPrompt = 3,
    names         = [ ];

// as long as namesToPrompt is truthy, prompt for inputs
while( namesToPrompt-- ) {
    names.push( prompt('Please enter a name') );
}

// sort our array
names.sort( byName );

// and print it
document.getElementById( 'msg' ).textContent = names.join(',');

function byName( a, b ) {
    return a.localeCompare( b );
}
```

If you want to let the user enter all names at once, you could go like

```
var inputNames = prompt( 'Please enter three names','Names' );

document.getElementById( 'msg' ).textContent = inputNames
                                                 .split( /,\s+/ )   // split by any amount of white-space characters in a row
                                                 .sort( byName )
                                                 .join( ',' );

function byName( a, b ) {
    return a.localeCompare( b );
}
```

Comment: Clicked by accident xD this is basically how I would recommend doing it. although, you could just do `.sort()` without the function.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest letting them do all three names at once. Solely for the fact that they could enter `jeff,tim,tyler` or `jeff tim tyler` or jeff, tim, tyler` or any other random cases and you would have to account for all of them for it to work. You could do `.split(/\s|,|,\s)` but even that probably wouldn't cover all the edge cases. And that also wouldn't allow for full names, like `jeff shaver` since it has a space.

Comment: @JeffShaver Is there a way to have a prompt box have three input boxes? Or will I need to just have three separate prompt boxes appear?  If so, how do I get the program to print the information from all three prompt boxes? I at one point got it the program to prompt 3 separate boxes, but it would only print the input from the last box.

Comment: @jAndy For some reason when I try the code you wrote out, it prompts 3 boxes for input, but it won't print anything on the page.

Comment: @AnnikaZwirn any sophisticated dialog (like more input elements) must be created either on your own (html+css) or you use one of the many UI frameworks available. The `prompt()` method is a very simple, quick'n dirty element. If nothing gets printed, try `.innerHTML` instead of `.textContent`, legacy IE browsers don't know about it for instance.